# How to dependency injection using ocLazyLoad

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, oclazyload

I'm using ocLazyLoad and I have some external angular libraries (Like `Chart.js` and `pascalprecht.translate`) and I need to lazy load them in some routes, as you know, for the common angular module dependency injection should be like:

```
var angularApp = angular.module('myApp',
     ['oc.lazyLoad', 'pascalprecht.translate', 'chart.js']);
```

Now, I just need to lazy loading `pascalprecht.translate` in one of my **`controllers`** and also lazy loading `chart.js`, in another **`controller`**, but I still need to add inject them to ***`myApp`*** module but I don't know how to inject and I do not use `$stateProvider`

**I tried this my controller that I needed chart.js:**

```
//Load here.
//$ocLazyLoad.load('./panel/dist/test.js');
angular.module('myApp', ['chart.js', [
 './panel/dist/static/chart.min.js',
 './panel/dist/static/angular-chart.min.js'
]]);

$ocLazyLoad.load('./panel/dist/static/chart.min.js');
$ocLazyLoad.load('./panel/dist/static/angular-chart.min.js');
```

**But I got this error:**

> angular-chart.min.js:10Uncaught Error: Chart.js library needs to
>   included, see http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

Answer (score 0):

First, you do not need to inject chart.js in your dependency injection, this should be your **module**:

```
var angularApp = angular.module('myApp', [ 'oc.lazyLoad' ]);
```

Now, you want to have access to some libraries from different controllers *(let's say routes)*, as you said you do not use `$stateProvider` which means you do not use **[`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)** *(which is a third-party library to work with routes and URLs)*.

This is my suggestion (just a simple solution):

```
angularApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController',
        resolve: {
            store: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load(
                    {
                        serie: true,
                        name: "chart.js",
                        files: [
                            "./static/chart.min.js",
                            "./static/chart-angular.min.js",
                        ]
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    });

        $routeProvider.when('/needs-translate', { 
        templateUrl: 'views/needs-translate.html',
        controller: 'translateController',
        resolve: {
            store: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load(
                    {
                        serie: true,
                        name: "pascalprecht.translate",
                        files: [
                            "./static/translate.js"
                        ]
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });

    // use the HTML5 History API
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix = '!';
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

By the way, if you are using `ui.router`, this [Github issue](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/issues/353#issuecomment-252423761) would be useful for you