# how loading more than one module and dependency injection in one route in Angular app using ocLazyLoad?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, oclazyload

I could inject lazy loaded libraries to my modules according to this [Stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875533/how-to-dependency-injection-using-oclazyload/39933453#39933453), but the answer is just describing and working with injecting one module (even with more than one file). But, I have a route and I want to lazy loading two libraries in that route (`ngMap` and `ngFileUpload`)

Here is my code with one dependency injection:

```
$routeProvider.when('/test-route', {
    templateUrl: 'test.html',
    controller: 'testController',
    resolve: {
        store: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load(
                {
                    serie: true,
                    name: "ngMap",
                    files: [
                        "./files/ngMap.js"
                    ]
                }
            );
        }
    }
});
```

But I also need `ngFileUpload` in this route, but I don't know how to lazy loading it. Help me please

Thank you very much
This website is verry Useful and Helpful